# Installing without package manager, why does executable binary fail with "command not found" unless I make the commands start with "./"?

Tags: terminal

I'm learning to use GNU/Linux and I want to know how to install programs that cannot be installed with the package manager.

I downloaded the tarball with the Linux 64-bit Binaries (including one called "haxelib"), extracted it, changed directory in the terminal to their location (~/Downloads/things/haxe_20201231082044_5e33a78aa/), and used chmod to make them executable.

If I try a command such as `haxelib list`, then the terminal returns
`haxelib: command not found`

If I try `./haxelib list` (the same command but with `./` at the start) instead, then the command works as expected.

Why can't I use it without the `./`? Programs installed with the package manager can be used without the `./`.

Edit: I should probably also ask: where should I put the files from the tarball? Should they all go together in the same place? I have a feeling that a folder named "things" in my Downloads folder is not the best place for them.

Comment: This is determined by your PATH. If the executable is one of the directories listed with `echo "$PATH"`, then you can invoke it with name only. The package manager will install binaries in e.g. `/usr/bin`

Comment: I look at my PATH and it has fewer than 10 things, none of which seem specific to a single program. I think moving the binaries to `/usr/bin` is exactly what I needed. Thank you!